# JOptionPane doesn't work with INFORMATION_MESSAGE

Tags: java, swing

I don't understand why in my code one JOptionPane with WARNING_MESSAGE working well while with INFORMATION_MESSAGE not. This is my method when I push a button:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    menu.jCheckBox1.setSelected(true);
    //menu.status=3;

    if(!(jTextField1.getText().equals(""))){
        OutputStream outStream = inizio.p.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pWriter = new PrintWriter(outStream);
        pWriter.println("3");
        pWriter.println(label[0]+" "+jTextField1.getText());
        pWriter.flush();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All registers are set to "+jTextField1.getText()+" ns.", "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        //jTextField1.setText(null);
    }
    else{
        Exception e = new Exception("Error!");
        Component f = null;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Please insert delay!", e.getMessage(), JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

    }

}
```

Why the `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All registers are set to "+jTextField1.getText()+" ns.", "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);` doesn't appear when the program enters in the if condition while the `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Please insert delay!", e.getMessage(), JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);` works well when there is the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any mistake in your JOptionPane code. There may be mistake in the code given below. check for that.

```
pWriter.println(label[0]+" "+jTextField1.getText());
```